# Not getting similar shape in edit and object mode

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

Im not getting similar shape to my model. When im in object mode look that the end is connected and when i go in edit mode its far away from the end to join. Whats going wrong with my model. i have remove doubles also yet not get a success. Any solution [image]

Comment: how to apply scale in edit mode?

Comment: @sorry I meant,  did you apply scale in object mode?

Comment: @cegaton i have attach the file u can go through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you hid any geometry using the hide function in editmode (H-Key). If so unhide the geometry using **ALT-H** in edit-mode.

Comment: u mean that i have 2 mesh. I have check it there is a single mesh only.

Comment: No. There may be hidden vertices in the mesh. Press Alt+H in edit mode.

Comment: @ f59838 & leander ur correct i have press alt+h in edit mode and its not reacting now may i know whats the problem

Comment: If you still have problems, upload your blend file- others can help you more easily.